# Смена языков для приложения Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

у меня есть небольшое SPA приложение на Vue.js. Возникла необходимость в том, чтобы отправлять с сервера в зависимости от страны клиент русскую или английскую версию страницу. С тем как определить страну я разобрался, но а вот как лучше всего реализовать, различные версии страниц для разных языков, чтобы было как можно меньше дублирования кода и как можно более удобно. В качестве данных я использую json файл. Предполагал хранить два json файла для русских данных, но не знаю как выставить в webpack чтобы получалось два бандла...

Вообщем подскажите пожалуйста наиболее выгодное решение, как уже говорил ранее в качестве системы сборки использую Webpack. Может в Webpack есть какой-либо плагин или во Vue или быть может есть какие-то другие библиотеки...

Answer (score 0):

Для англоязычной версии идешь на сервер, допустим, по адресу `.../api/lang/eng`,
Справедливо так же и для других языков.

В своем приложении делаешь следующий финт ушами:

```
const fetchData = async (lang) => {
  const data = await fetch(`.../api/lang/${lang}`);
  return await data.json()
}
```

Ну а дальше кладешь это в переменную и пользуешься.

**P.S.**

На продакшене так лучше не писать, а то можно и ногу себе отстрелить нечаянно. Лучше обернуть все это в try...catch блок, как [тут](https://gist.github.com/msmfsd/fca50ab095b795eb39739e8c4357a808)

Comment: Мне не нужно делать запроса, данные в json файле хранятся, и собираются при сборке приложения

Comment: @QuickDzen Тогда разбиваешь на `json` файлы по языкам и так же фетчишь.